# C# parse outlook calendar item

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook

I am writing an application that employees in our business use to capture their timesheets. My colleague that helps with the development got a brilliant idea to add a feature that an employee can drag and drop their calendar entries from Microsoft Outlook and a timesheet entry will be created with the correct details.

It was easy to create the drag and drop feature but only the meeting title and location get exposed. The interpretation code is this:

```
Object item = (object)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
textBox1.Text = item.ToString();
```

The result I get is this:

> Time Sheet parameters and data capturing strategy (East Meeting Room 3)

I have tested it by dragging it into Microsoft Word and then there just appears an Outlook item on which you can double click to open the event.

Is there some way I can access the meeting's start and end time in my application?

Edit: I have tested Office Interop libraries and it works like a charm, though I would like to avoid the use of that. People in our office have different versions of Microsoft Office and I could not be sure that it would work on every PC.